# Thread reuse in Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, session, tomcat, web-applications

Tomcat uses a thread pool and reuses threads 
I was wondering does it reuse threads *across sessions* or across requests?

Comment: do you mean `reuse request objects across sessions`?

Comment: do you mean `reuse threads acrss sessions or across requests`? Anyway, I shouldn't make any assumption about threads. The only valid assumption is `only-one thread will process my request and then will be put to wait more job`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Across request and sessions. Everything. If a thread couldn't be used by different sessions your server would collapse in a couple of seconds/minutes, when 300 users get their session id's (and respective threads be reserved) and user number 301 want to access.

Think of it as:

```
server waiting for request:
on request:
  obtain free thread from pool
  put that thread to process request (by example: doGet(Req, Resp))
  when finished return thread to pool
```

Every request to server (from whoever is) is processed by the first free thread in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html) states below.

> The Executor represents a thread pool that can be shared between components in Tomcat. Historically there has been a thread pool per connector created but this **allows you to share a thread pool**, between (primarly) connector but also other components when those get configured to support executors

Comment: Does this mean different contexts could share the same threads. And maybe leaking thread local variables.

Comment: @j4nbur53, to my understanding, yes. thread local variables are shared among different requests that happen to use same threads.